# Nf_hook_ops returns incompatible pointer when assigning to hook_func -C -Linux -Netfilter

Tags: c, linux, pointers, kernel-module, netfilter

I am trying to write my own Netfilter kernel module on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I am trying to assign hook_func to nfho.hook but I get the following error:

`error: assignment from incompatible pointer type 
[-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
nfho.hook = hook_func;`

I have looked on other solutions, mostly ended up on double checking parameters including changing `*skb` to `**skb`. I have read that the parameters might depend on the kernel version but couldn't find how to find out the right parameters to be passed.

How can I get that to work and also how do I check what parameters should be passed in hook_func on my kernel version?

Full code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;  //struct holding set of hook function options

// function to be called by hook
unsigned int hook_func(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *skb, const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{
  struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb); 
  struct tcphdr *tcp_header;
  if (ip_header->protocol == 6)
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO "TCP Packet\n");
    tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *)(skb_transport_header(skb)+20);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Source Port: %u\n", tcp_header->source);
   }

  return NF_ACCEPT;                                                                  
}

int init_module()
{
  nfho.hook = hook_func;
  nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING; 
  nfho.pf = PF_INET;                 
  nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;   
  nf_register_hook(&nfho);           
  return 0;            
}
```

Comment: `how do I check what parameters should be passed in hook_func on my kernel version?` - Just check definition of `struct nf_hook_ops` (and `nf_hookfn` type) in the headers for your kernel. Those definitions are in `include/linux/netfilter.h` file relative to the kernel build directory. This directory is usually referred by `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>/build`.

Comment: Thanks!

I have figured it out using :
locate netfilter.h
In my case netfilter.h was located in different path therefore I couldn't check it.