# nfhook (netfilter) error: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, netfilter

I have seen this page with similar error message: [Nf_hook_ops returns incompatible pointer when assigning to hook_func -C -Linux -Netfilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741943/nf-hook-ops-returns-incompatible-pointer-when-assigning-to-hook-func-c-linux/44145678#44145678)

However, it didn't give a clear answer to how to solve the issue. The author for that question says that he found out his netfilter.h is located elsewhere which caused the trouble, but for me I found out that all the four files included are in the correct directory (usr/src/linux-headers-4.8.0-22-generic/include/linux in my case).

Following is my code which should help clarify better.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;

unsigned int hook_func_incoming(unsigned int hooknum, struct sk_buff *sskb, 
const struct net_device *in, const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)
(struct sk_buff *)){
    return NF_DROP;
}

int init_module(){
    nfho.hook = hook_func_incoming;
    nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;
    nfho.pf = PF_INET;
    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;
    nf_register_hook(&nfho);
    printk(KERN_INFO "SIMPLE FIREWALL LOADED\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The exact error message is this:

**error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  nfho.hook = hook_func_incoming;
            ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors**

Please let me know what I should do to be able to compile my netfilter, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

In the (IMHO) latest (released) netfilter [version](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/netfilter.h#L60), `nf_hookfn` (the base type of `nf_hook_ops.hook`) is defined as follows:

```
typedef unsigned int nf_hookfn(void *priv,
                   struct sk_buff *skb,
                   const struct nf_hook_state *state);
```

Your function `hook_func_incoming` does not match this signature, you should adopt it.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me solve the issue. However, can you tell me more about the first and the third parameters? I can't find any related documentation online (I do know the information about the second parameter though).

Answer (score 0):

Third parameter is this data structure. In the new definition of the hook function, they wanted to combine the old parameters in a single data structure. So, if you need the out device, you can get it from this state parameter.

```
struct nf_hook_state {
        unsigned int hook;
        int thresh;
        u_int8_t pf;
        struct net_device *in;
        struct net_device *out;
        struct sock *sk;
        struct net *net;
        struct nf_hook_entry __rcu *hook_entries;
        int (*okfn)(struct net *, struct sock *, struct sk_buff *);
};
```

priv is a field inside the struct nf_hook_ops. You can set it to any value in your own module and access it in your hook function.

```
struct nf_hook_ops {
        struct list_head        list;

        /* User fills in from here down. */
        nf_hookfn               *hook;
        struct net_device       *dev;
        void                    *priv;
        u_int8_t                pf;
        unsigned int            hooknum;
        /* Hooks are ordered in ascending priority. */
        int                     priority;
};
```